# how to convert select into update statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a select statement which I need to convert it into Update statement.

```
SELECT GUID,seq original_seq_no, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
FROM CHK_SEQ;
```

what actually the above query does is, suppose I have a multiple records with a unique GUID and the value of column SEQ is 6,9,10 in table CHK_SEQ. Then running the above query changes the value of SEQ as 1,2,3 which is new_seq_no.

can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle and SQL server

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Sql-Server 2005 and above):

```
With cte as (
  Select GUID,seq, row_number() over ( partition by GUID order by seq) AS new_seq_no
  From CHK_SEQ
)
Update c
Set c.seq = new_seq_no
From CHK_SEQ c 
     Join cte on c.Guid = cte.Guid and c.seq = cte.seq;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply guys, will this query will run in Oracle too?

Comment: I am not sure about Oracle. Try it with a Select instead Update and let us know...

Comment: While trying to execute the query I am getting this error SQL Error: The executeQuery method must return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with cte 
AS
(
SELECT GUID,seq original_seq_no, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER ( PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
FROM CHK_SEQ
)

update  CHK_SEQ
set     CHK_SEQ.seq = r.new_seq_no
from    cte r
where CHK_SEQ.seq = r.original_seq_no AND CHK_SEQ.GUID= r.GUID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. any idea how can I make it work in Oracle too.

Comment: While trying to execute the query I am getting this error SQL Error: The executeQuery method must return a result set

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into CHK_SEQ 
using
    SELECT rowid as rid, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GUID ORDER BY seq) AS new_seq_no
    FROM CHK_SEQ
) t on (chk_seq.rowid = t.rid)
when matched then update
   set seq = new_seq_no;
```